# how to get parent field name(lable) using describe call

Tags: apex

In my controller I have a List of string. This list contains The Object Name, and the Field Name. So, I need to get the "Label" Name of this fields.

so Is there a way to get parent field name(lable) using describe call

like this:

```
Map<String, SobjectField> fieldMap = Contact.getsObjectType().getDescribe().Fields.getMap();
System.debug('**********'+fieldMap.get('Account.Name').getDescribe().getLabel());
```

but it is throwing an error

```
system.nullpointerexception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a Contact or Opportunity Object (Account.Name) so this example will get you that:

```
String str = 'Account.Name';
String[] obj_fld = str.split('\\.');
Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(obj_fld[0]);

String lbl = targetType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(obj_fld[1]).getDescribe().getLabel();
system.debug(logginglevel.error,lbl);
```

You can optimize / error trap as you see fit.

Comment: thanx for ur reply sir 
but i need account name field label from contact on global describe to contact

Comment: and also i need owner name label of contact using global describe